# Error compiling lambda with bounded generic

Tags: java, generics, lambda

The following is a contrived, self-contained example I created to demonstrate a problem I'm having with a much more complicated program:

```
public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubObject[] array = new SubObject[5];
        Iterator<? extends SuperObject> iterator 
                = Arrays.asList((SuperObject[]) array).iterator();
        Iterable<? extends SuperObject> iterable = () -> iterator;
    }
}

class SuperObject {};

class SubObject extends SuperObject{};
```

This does not compile:

```
MyTest.java:9: error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
        Iterable<? extends SuperObject> iterable = () -> iterator;
                                                         ^
    Iterator<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Iterator<SuperObject>
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends SuperObject from capture of ? extends SuperObject
```

I know I could simplify the generics, replacing `<? extends SuperObject>` with `<SuperObject>`.  But this would defeat my purpose in the larger program.  Why this error?

Comment: May I just ask why having `Iterator<SuperObject>` and `Iterable<SuperObject>` would defeat the purpose of your program?

Comment: Consider a super container class and a set of sub container classes that extend the super container.  The super container defines an abstract iterable() method that returns an Iterable<Widget>. Each sub container contains an array of a class that extends Widget, and implements iterable() to return an Iterable over the array.  If the array in a sub container is implemented using ArrayList<ExtOfWidget>, I can't seem to create an Iterable that can be returned by iterable(), i.e. an Iterable<Widget>.  Can't cast ArrayList<ExtOfWidget> to ArrayList<Widget>.

Comment: To continue:  However it all works if iterable() returns an Iterable<? extends Widget>, at least except for the problem I present in this question.

Comment: Your example is a bit convoluted. You can demonstrate the same issue like this: `Iterator<?> iterator = Collections.emptyIterator(); Iterable<?> iterable = () -> iterator;`

Comment: Either way, the example serves to demonstrate the error, but not why it's actually a problem. Can you elaborate on your sample use case above so we can understand what you're really trying to do?

Comment: The error makes more sense if you try writing the lambda as an explicit anonymous class. You can't do `new Iterable<? extends SuperObject>() {...}` so the compiler performs capture conversion on the target type of the lambda which causes the error. It's sort of like if you tried to do `(Iterable<SuperObject>) () -> iterator`. Also see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Radiodef's comment, I was able to figure this out.  The trick, as explained in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html, is to use a helper function:

```
public class MyTest4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubObject[] array = new SubObject[5];
        Iterator<? extends SuperObject> iterator
                = Arrays.asList((SuperObject[]) array).iterator();
        Iterable<? extends SuperObject> iterable = getIterable(iterator);
    }

    static <T> Iterable<T> getIterable(Iterator<T> iterator) {
        return () -> iterator;
    }

}

class SuperObject {};

class SubObject extends SuperObject{};
```

Comment: Interesting observation. If one could write "lambdas with type-arguments" in Java, one could do the same thing inline: 
`Iterator<? extends Blah> a = ...; 
Iterable<? extends Blah> b = (<T>(Iterator<T> iterator) -> (Iterable<T>)(() -> iterator)).apply(a);`. This would be akin to "inline syntax for natural transformations from `Iterator<->` to `Iterable<->`". Unfortunately, this isn't valid (yet). +1

Comment: Note that the type cast in the first statement is obsolete; you can simply do `Iterator<? extends SuperObject> iterator = Arrays.asList(array).iterator();`, but that does *not* imply that you *should*. As [the same tutorial states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html): “*Using a wildcard as a return type should be avoided because it forces programmers using the code to deal with wildcards*”. In your example, no-one is forcing you, you are rather forcing yourself, but keep that in mind for whatever real life scenario you simplified to this example.

Comment: And just for records, you can do `Iterable<? extends SuperObject> iterable = Arrays.<SuperObject>asList(array)::iterator;` which would even be a semantically correct `Iterable`, is it isn’t just a one-time iteration only iterable. Still, there is no real reason to force having a wildcard in the variable…